# How to find visible child in hidden parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a div which has the error message span visible in it. I tried the following codes but it works only when the container is visible otherwise it is unable to find in it.

Can someone share the reason and solution to it?

#### Code 1:

Using [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

```
$(".has-warning:visible").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var divs = ["wReq_div", "mcatIsq_div", "glDetail_div"];
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if ($("#" + divs[i] + " #" + id).length) {
                    console.log("found in " + divs[i]);
                    return false;
            }
    }
});
```

This gives true for the container if it's visible otherwise not.

#### Code 2:

Using [$.contains](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/)

```
$(".has-warning:visible").each(function(){
  var id = this.id;
  var divs = ["wReq_div","mcatIsq_div","glDetail_div"];
  for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    if($.contains($("#"+divs[i])[0],$("#"+id)[0])){
        console.log("found in " + divs[i]);
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

It's also working only if the container is visible.

So my main problem is:

1. Parent is hidden and child has `display` not `none`, how to find that shown child in the hidden parent
2. To find that which parent div(hidden) has an error div with given id so that I can show that parent div.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwbaOX)

I don't want to use the method of changing class from a hidden one to visible one to display my errorMsg as I'll have to do a lot of changes in multiple files.

Comment: You can select hidden elements by using `:hidden` Selector refer this link https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: But the problem is to find a visible child having parent hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs

> jQuery( ":visible" )
>
> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

If a parent is hidden, all it's children will also be hidden. So, `$(".has-warning:visible")` will not return the child elements, even if they're `not` hidden.
you need to rely on the display property of the child elements, rather than the :visible attribute and try something like this,

```
function checkMsg1(){
  $(".has-warning").each(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var i=0;
    var divs = ["wReq_div", "mcatIsq_div", "glDetail_div"];
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if ($("#" + divs[i] +" #"+id).css("display") !== 'none') {
                $("#" + divs[i]).show();    
            }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I also tried that approach but the problem with that approach is that it selects and iterates over all the elements of `has-warning` class. Does it impact the performance of my code..? shouldn't I select the needful elements only...?

Comment: I don't think it would impact the performance unless you're iterating over thousands of elements and performing DOM updates for each iteration. If you're concerned, you could try hiding the parent elements instead of hiding the child and try to find its parent.

Comment: OK, I got this. Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used following code to overcome this problem, Please suggest if you have better one:

```
var divs = ["wReq_div","mcatIsq_div","glDetail_div"];
$(".has-warning").each(function(){
  if($(this).css("display") != "none"){
    var id = this.id;
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
      if($.contains($("#"+divs[i])[0],$("#"+id)[0])){
          console.log("found in " + divs[i]);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But it first selects all the divs and may increase time.

Answer (score 0):

you will not find `.has-warning:visible` as its parent is not visible. But you can check for parent div if it is hidden or not.

```
$(".has-warning").each(function() {
  if($(this).css("display") != "none"){
      var id = this.id;
      var i=0;
      var divs = ["wReq_div:hidden", "mcatIsq_div:hidden", "glDetail_div:hidden"];
      for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          if ($("#" + divs[i] + " #" + id).length) {
               alert("found in " + divs[i] + " " + id);
               // Add code to display that div
          }
          else {
              alert("not found in " + divs[i]+ " " + id);
          }
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: This will give me all the parents having the child with class `has-warning` but I want only the visible ones with hidden parents. With this approach, I can select only in the hidden parents, what if the parent is also visible... So can't go with this solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: **Parent is hidden and child has display not none, how to find that shown child in the hidden parent** isn't this what you wanted to achieve ? then why you need visible parents ?

Comment: But your answer is not giving me only the **visible** children with `has-warning` class, It's giving me all the children with `has-warning` class.